# Why is 2-digit not working for Date.toLocaleTimeString?

Tags: javascript, date

I would swear I'm doing this right, as described [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```
(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
})
```

But this is outputting `"3:13:22 AM"`....the hour is not 2-digit. What am I doing wrong? I'm very tired.

Comment: Two digit for the hours only seems to work when combined with hour12 false. It's probably somewhere in [*ECMA–402*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hour:'2-digit'` property seems to be ignored by major Chrome, Firefox, Safari and NodeJS. Instead they apply the option `hour12:` value (i.e. 12 or 24-hour notation) instead:

> `hour12:true` results in "3:00:00 PM" since no one really writes "03:00:00 PM" with the presence of `PM`. Doing so may confuse others into thinking that this is 24-hour notation (i.e. 3 AM) if one reads quickly and misses the `PM` at the end.
>
> `hour12:false` results in "15:00:00" and "PM" is no longer needed.

So in your example, if you wanted 24-hour notation, just use:

```js
let date = (new Date("17 May 2019 3:13:22 AM")).toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour12: false,
    hour: '2-digit', 
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
})

console.log(date); //03:13:22
```

Comment: Note also that it's trivial to parse out the hour and `%` by 12 to convert from 24 to 12.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, are you wanting the output in 24 hours?

```
let date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour12: false
});

console.log(date);
```

EDIT: It seems that your original question is an issue that's been covered prior but classified as a bug.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507037

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. set `hour12 to false`. So that you can get 2 digit hours starting with 0 if less than 10.

```js
var a = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour12: false,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
});

console.log(a)
```

Comment: This actually solves it.... but keep in mind that this overrides the default locale behavior regarding to the 12/24 hours format.